# Cannot find module 'typescript'

Tags: javascript, typescript

Yesterday works but today I have this error.
I reinstall globally and local

```
npm i --save-dev typescript
npm i -g typescript
```

and lower version

```
npm install  -g typescript@3.9.4
```

remove from directory AppData\Roaming\npm but this doesnt work.
remove node_modules too

tsconfig

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "removeComments": true,
        "outFile": "app.js",
        "lib": ["es2017", "dom"]
    },
    "files":[
        "app.ts",
        "inter.ts",
    ]
}
```

I run command

```
npx ts
```

and then I had got error :

> Cannot find module 'typescript'

```
$ npm -v
6.13.4
$ node -v
v12.16.1
```

Comment: So, this is the package you are trying to run? [`npm:ts`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts).

Comment: I run compile with command npx ts

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes you may need to link the package manually, as it may conflict if there's an existing `node_modules` already.

Try this:

> npm link typescript

An alternative solution would be to delete the `node_modules` folder and then run `npm install` again.

Comment: npm link typescript and delete node_module didn't help. thank for your help.  In another computer perfect ......

Comment: @zloctb I've read somewhere that it has to be done in this particular order, for some reason: `npm install -g typescript` `npm link typescript`

Answer (score 1):

Add `"typescript": "~4"` to package.json's devDependencies works for me.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to follow the advised steps in exact sequence:

1. Delete node_module folder
2. Delete package-lock.json
3. npm install
4. npm install typescript
5. npm link typescript
6. npm start
7. For any further missing dependencies do npm install [dep] followed by npm link [dep]

Answer (score 0):

Update your node version, node -v v12.16.1 is too old.

You can do it with https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

```
nvm use 18
```